# IntelliLock vs Net Reactor

Tags: license-key, net-reactor, intellilock

What is/are the difference(s) between these two? And why would I want one or the other or both?  This is for a commercial .NET C# WPF application that will be packaged via WiX.  I will need a trial license to purchased license capability.

Answer (score 19):

I came into the same question and have the luck to have their Eziriz CTO replied:

> You only need one product. .NET Reactor is 100% concentrated on
>   protection without making a compromise to the licensing system. On the
>   other side IntelliLock is 100% concentrated on licensing and the
>   corresponding protection functionality is optimized for the licensing
>   system. That is the reason why IntelliLock can even provide licensing
>   support for Linux (Mono) or the Compact Framework or offer full
>   license management support via an ASP.NET interface. The protection of
>   IntelliLock is not as strong as the one from .NET Reactor but the
>   differences could be kept within a limit. IntelliLock can provide
>   Obfuscation/Control Flow Obfuscation/Inject Invalid MetaData and
>   String Encryption even without a restriction.
>
> A significant difference between both products is the 100% managed
>   solution of IntelliLock. The managed nature of IntelliLock allows you
>   to create assemblies which are still cross-platform compatible and use
>   of very flexible and advanced licensing features. IntelliLock takes
>   all advantages the .NET Framework do offer. Therefore it is often used
>   to protect component libraries. In case you want to have the extra bit
>   of ultimate protection .NET Reactor should be the first choice. In
>   contrast to IntelliLock, .NET Reactor injects native protection code.
>   Therefore it is a question of preference which tool to choose to
>   protect your .NET assemblies. :)

To simplify, .NET Reactor and Intellilocks do more or less the same thing with .NET Reactor being stronger on the protection algorithm and with Intellilocks having an easier GUI but a weaker protection strength as compared with .NET Reactor.

I tried both. I suggest going with .NET Reactor; while not as user-friendly as Intellilocks, .NET Reactor does everything Intellilocks can do and with stronger protection.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to point out as it has already been stated that if you need ANY other system than a standard Windows Desktop system, then you will want to use IntelliLock. That's where I am at now. I'm needing to use the licensing on a .NET Compact Framework system (Windows CE/Mobile) so I have chosen IntelliLock. I greatly appreciate the above explanations as this made it clear for me based on what I read on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Reactor is more protection focused, Intellilock is more licensing focused. [This](http://www.eziriz.com/) page lists most of the features.